# Combing the data of a table in hive

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

Need to combine the data in a hive table in one row. The intention is to capture the data/ value other than `'N'` i.e. whatever value is present other than `'N'` should be captured for all the `'col1'` values

Table1:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
-----------------------------
GHY   BG  Q    N    N    N
GHY   BG  N    T    N    N
GHY   BG  N    N    A    N
GHY   BG  N    N    N    Z
```

Tried with the following query:

```
Select col1, col2,array(
max(CASE WHEN col3 == 'Q' THEN 'Q' ELSE 'None' END),
max(CASE WHEN col4 == 'T' THEN 'T' ELSE 'None' END),
max(CASE WHEN col5 == 'A' THEN 'A' ELSE 'None' END),
max(CASE WHEN col6 == 'Z' THEN 'Z' ELSE 'None' END))
FROM table1 GROUP BY col1,col2;
```

and got the below:

Actual O/P:

```
GHY BG ['None','None','A','None']
```

Expected O/P:

```
GHY BG ['Q','T','A','Z']
```

Not getting the point of error :(

Update_1:

After removing 'max' from the query:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 2:11 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'Q'
```

Update_2:

```
select col1,col2,collect_set(col)
from (select col1,col2,t.col
      from tbl 
      lateral view explode(array(col3,col4,col5,col6)) t as col
      where t.col <> 'N'
     ) t
```

Error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'col1'
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `max()` ?

Comment: @Tony Updated the question with O/P. After removing the 'max'

Comment: Nevermind the `max()`. I did not check properly check the query, sorry.

Comment: why is `N` not in the array output?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Explained it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution (inspired by the provided ones) is:

```
Select col1,col2,array(concat(max(col3),max(col4),max(col5),max(col6)))
group by col1,col2;
```

Note:

`max()` will pick the maximum value. So you may need to change your unwanted values to something like `'aa'`. Otherwise the other values might be picked.

Example1:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
-----------------------------
GHY   BG  Q    N    N    N
GHY   BG  N    T    N    N
GHY   BG  N    N    A    N
GHY   BG  N    N    N    Z
```

Result:

```
['Q','T','N','Z']
```

Example2:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
-----------------------------
GHY   BG  Q    a    a    a
GHY   BG  a    T    a    a
GHY   BG  a    a    A    a
GHY   BG  a    a    a    Z
```

Result:

```
['Q','T','A','Z']
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is the simplest and most effective one.

Answer (score 4):

Use `explode` to get one row per column for a combination of col1,col2 and aggregate them with a `collect_set`.

```
select col1,col2,collect_set(col)
from (select col1,col2,t.col
      from tbl 
      lateral view explode(array(col3,col4,col5,col6)) t as col
      where t.col <> 'N'
     ) t
group by col1,col2
```

Comment: Thank you but getting an error. Have updated it as "Update_2".

Answer (score 4):

This query produces expected result:

```
with Table1 as --your test data
(
 select stack(4,
   'GHY','BG','Q','N','N','N',
   'GHY','BG','N','T','N','N',
   'GHY','BG','N','N','A','N',
   'GHY','BG','N','N','N','Z') as (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
)

select col1, col2,array(
       nvl(max(CASE WHEN col3 = 'Q' THEN 'Q' END),'None'),
       nvl(max(CASE WHEN col4 = 'T' THEN 'T' END),'None'),
       nvl(max(CASE WHEN col5 = 'A' THEN 'A' END),'None'), 
       nvl(max(CASE WHEN col6 = 'Z' THEN 'Z' END),'None'))
from Table1
group by col1, col2;
```

Result:

```
GHY BG  ["Q","T","A","Z"]
```